# Groovy: How to get unix time of a certain date instead of current Date?

Tags: unix, groovy

I have this code:

```
Date toDate = new Date();
Date fromDate = toDate - 30
long unixToTime = currentDate.getTime() / 1000
long unixFromDate = fromDate.getTime() / 1000
```

With this code I get the unix Time for the current Date and the unix Time for a date 30 days before. What I instead want is to get a code, where I can enter a specific `toDate` (e.g. 31-12-2020, 10:00:00) and then get the unix time of this instead.

Note: I am an absolute beginner regarding groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy for manual input is the builder `of` from `LocalDateTime`.  If you
have many dates or they come from a different source, you might be
better off to parse directly into `Instant`.  From the `Instant` you can
get the seconds since the epoch.  E.g.

```
java.time.LocalDateTime.of(2020,2,24,16,42).toInstant(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC).epochSecond
// → 1582562520
```